# How to prevent bsValueChange from firing on page load in angular?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have been using ngx-bootstrap's datepicker to listen for an onchange event so that I could fetch data whenever the user changes the date from input.

Everything works fine except for the fact `bsValueChange` fires initially on page load which returns an `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type date: "Invalid Date"`.

Here is my datepicker code block

```
<input class="form-control" #drp="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker [(ngModel)]="bsRangeValue" [bsConfig]="{ rangeInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }"
  (bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)">
```

I have looked into [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2825) github issue as well but this is not working for me either as `ngModelChange` doesn't work anymore.

I only want `bsValueChange` to fire once when the entire page has loaded.

Comment: Can you add more info on what is being done onValueChane ?

Comment: So, whenever any date is selected, onValueChange is fired to fetch data from the database with the help of a service to display it on the frontend .

Comment: and why can't you do with null checks in this method ?

Answer (score 4):

use onHidden event instead of bsvalueChange

Comment: I'm using an inline picker. So kindly give this Solution.

Answer (score 1):

While page is loading, the `onValueChange($event)` method will be called. I found no way to prevent this instead you can try something like this.
Have a number variable declared outside the method.

```
counter = 0;
OnChangeValue($event){
     this.counter = this.counter+1;
     if(this.counter>2 && event.length!=0){
      -- Proceed with your code --
}
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this problem by setting a component handleDatepickerEvents flag which starts as false and is set to true in ngAfterViewInit().

The onValueChange() function just needs to ignore changes when handleDatepickerEvents is false.

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: onDateChange(date: Date, isStart): void {
    if (this.finishLoading) {
      console.log('isStart:', isStart);
      const dateRange = this.form.get('dateRange') as FormGroup;
      dateRange.get(isStart ? 'startDate' : 'endDate').patchValue(moment(date).format('DD/MM/yyyy'));
    }

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.finishLoading = true;
  }

Answer (score 1):

You said ngModelChange didn't solved your problem. I had the same problem with Angular 9 and ngx-bootstrap 5.6.2 wich was solved changing from
`(bsValueChange)="onDataFinalValueChange($event)"` to `(ngModelChange)="onDataFinalValueChange($event)"`